# How to load a dictionary only once in WCF serive

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service in which I implements some methods(Operartional Contract). I need to load some values from Excel to dictionary. I can load the values. But It gets loaded every time when service member gets accessed/consumed.

I don't want want to load every time. Its enough to load only once. How to achieve this.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
         Dictionary<string, List<MappingFields>> MappingCollections;
         public Service1()
            {
            MappingCollections = loadCodes(Location, fileName);
            } 
    }
    #region IService1 Members
         public void TicketTrack(Tickets[] tickets)
            {
             ............;
             ............;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
static Dictionary<string, List<MappingFields>> MappingCollections;

public void TicketTrack(Tickets[] tickets)
{
    if (MappingCollections == null) MappingCollections = loadCodes(Location, fileName);

    ...
}
```

This would check for the existence of an instance of mapping collections and if it doesn't exist, create it (could probably shunt that out to a utility method).

Answer (score 0):

You could use lazy to achieve that:

```
    private static Lazy<Dictionary<string, List<MappingFields>>> MappingCollections =
        new Lazy<Dictionary<string, List<MappingFields>>>(x => loadCodes(Location, fileName));

    public void TicketTrack(Tickets[] tickets)
    {
        var myData = MappingCollections.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a static variable:

```
private static Dictionary<string, List<MappingFields>> MappingCollections = loadCodes(Location, fileName);
```

Make method 'loadCodes' also static. This way the dictionary will be loaded only once for AppDomain.